# APOC Virtual Relationships and GDS

Tags: charts, neo4j, apoc

I want to create virtual relationships in Neo4j using APOC and run GDS algorithms like degree distributions. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, virtual nodes and relationships cannot be projected in GDS.

For example, if you try this query:

```
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Foo'], {name: 'xyz'}) YIELD node
RETURN gds.graph.project('t', node) AS g
```

You get an error like this (virtual entities have negative native IDs):

> Failed to invoke function `gds.graph.project`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GDS expects node ids to be positive. But got a negative id of `-2`.